# Try to compile, install and run imgmin on ubuntu server, but command not found

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, compilation, image-optimization

I try to use imgmin (written in C) by rflynn ([see on GitHub rflynn/imgmin](https://github.com/rflynn/imgmin)).
So I followed the instructions

```
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf libmagickwand-dev pngnq pngcrush pngquant
git clone https://github.com/rflynn/imgmin.git
cd imgmin
autoreconf -fi
./configure
make
sudo make install
imgmin original.jpg optimized.jpg
```

I compiled and installed it without any problems (or notices). But I can't run "imgmin", it always tells me:

```
-bash: imgmin: command not found
```

Where is my mistake? Thank you for any suggestion.
I'm running on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS with latest updates.

Comment: Where did it install that executable? Is it in your path?

Comment: The default install location root for most projects using `autoconf` (which this project seems to do) is `/usr/local/`. If `/usr/local/bin` is not in the path, commands placed there won't be found by the shell.

Comment: Check output of `sudo make install` for location of `imgmin`.

Comment: **I fixed it.**
I don't really know why it's working now, because I just rolled back the previous snapshot and repeated the instructions... finally it works. (so I like to vote to delete this post)

Thank you all for your help!!
Cheers

Comment: If `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`, you probably still need to do a `hash -r` to update `bash`'s cache. (or open a new shell of course)